# Understanding how to read a Boltzmann Distribution graph and how it relates to enthalpy, entropy, and temperature

Tags: physical-chemistry

[image: How do you read a Boltzmann distribution graph?]

I am having trouble understanding the how to read the graph and and thus don't understand how to connect it to the enthalpy, entropy, and temperature.

Comment: Sigh... For starters it would've been nice if they labeled the graphs...

Answer (score 1):

Here's my take on this question...

The Boltzmann distribution there just helps to indicate which direction is the direction of higher energy. It's up because the populations are smaller in that direction. Since the energies for $\ce{B}$ start higher, $\ce{B}$ must be higher in energy in *both* cases. From this, we conclude that:

$$\Delta H^{\varnothing} > 0$$

Entropy is defined as

$$S = k \ln \Omega$$

where $\Omega$ is the density of states. There are more energy states per unit energy in (b) for $\ce{B}$. I'm not sure how to conclude this for (a).

But from this, I do conclude that for (b),

$$\Delta S^{\varnothing} > 0$$

For (a), it's probably close to zero.

Now you can use:

$$\mathrm{K}_{eq}=\frac{\ce{[B]}}{\ce{[A]}}=e^{-\frac{\Delta G^{\varnothing}}{RT}} = e^{-\frac{\Delta H^{\varnothing}}{RT}}e^{\frac{\Delta S^{\varnothing}}{R}}$$

Notice that if $\Delta H^{\varnothing}>0$, then increasing $T$ means that the equilibrium constant gets smaller. If it's negative, then increasing $T$ means that the equilibrium constant gets bigger. In our case, enthalpy change is positive in both cases.

$\ce{B}$ exceeding $\ce{A}$ is simply a matter of whether or not the equilibrium constant can be greater than 1. This happens if the second term in the product (with entropy is large). Fortunately, $\Delta S^{\varnothing} > 0$ in (b). If you increase the temperature, you will drive the first term to 1, so it's possible to make $\ce{B}$ dominate the mixture at equilibrium.

This is less likely for (a) because I think the entropy change will be close to zero, so you can't make the second term very big.